# RcppArmadillo and arma namespace

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

Begin experienced in R but a complete newbie to C++, I wrote some functions with RcppArmadillo and am pretty enthusiastic about both its usability and speed. I'd now like to turn the functions into a package, using the function `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`.

This works okay as long as I explicitly use the `arma::` prefix before every Armadillo object (mat, colvec etc). However, if I put `using namespace arma;` at the beginning of my cpp file, and omit the `arma::` afterwards, I cannot load the newly created package and get tons of errors which make clear that the Armadillo namespace is not being recognized.

Any help/advice on how to fix this greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Fabian

PS: I tried the above on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, using R 3.0.2 and RcppArmadillo_0.4.000.4 in each case.

PS2: The attached cpp file (loosely following http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simulate-multivariate-normal/) illustrates my point. It works nicely if I source it into R via `sourceCpp` (from the Rcpp package), but leads to the problems mentioned above when I try to include it in a new package.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
colvec mvndrawC(colvec mu, mat sig) {

double k = mu.size();
colvec aux = as<colvec>(rnorm(k));
mat csig = chol(sig).t();
colvec out = mu + csig*aux;
return(out);

}
```

**EDIT: Details**

Here's the error output I get when I do the following:

1. Run the command `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("test2")`, thus creating folders for a new package "test2"
2. Paste the above code into a `.cpp` file, and copy it into the new `test2/src` folder
3. Trying to load the new `test2` package, by calling `load_all("test2")` from the `devtools` package

**Error messages (in Rstudio)**

```
Loading test2
Re-compiling test2
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL '/home/fabian/test2' --library='/tmp    
/RtmplfAET0'  \
--no-R --no-data --no-help --no-demo --no-inst --no-docs --no-exec --no-multiarch  \
--no-test-load --preclean 

* installing *source* package 'test2' ...
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/fabian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library   
/3.0/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/fabian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo  
/include"  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o 
RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp:10:1: error: 'colvec' does not name a type
RcppExports.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* test2_mvndrawC(SEXP, SEXP)':
RcppExports.cpp:16:40: error: 'colvec' was not declared in this scope
RcppExports.cpp:16:40: note: suggested alternative:
/home/fabian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits   
/typedef_mat.hpp:65:22: note:   'arma::colvec'
RcppExports.cpp:16:47: error: template argument 1 is invalid
RcppExports.cpp:16:55: error: expected initializer before 'mu'
RcppExports.cpp:17:40: error: 'mat' was not declared in this scope
RcppExports.cpp:17:40: note: suggested alternative:
/home/fabian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits   
/typedef_mat.hpp:63:22: note:   'arma::mat'
RcppExports.cpp:17:44: error: template argument 1 is invalid
RcppExports.cpp:17:52: error: expected initializer before 'sig'
RcppExports.cpp:18:16: error: expected ';' before '__result'
RcppExports.cpp:19:9: error: '__result' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'test2'
* removing '/tmp/RtmplfAET0/test2'
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
The following packages are referenced using Rcpp::depends attributes however are  
not listed in the Depends and LinkingTo fields of the package DESCRIPTION file: 
RcppArmadillo
```

**PS3:** The warning message at the end disappears if I drop the `// [[Rcpp...` line at the beginning of the file (but then I cannot source it via `sourceCpp`, so I let it in).

Comment: "Not enough information" -- your package should load either way.  But if in doubt, just prefix `arma::` ...

Comment: Indeed. In particular, even though compiler error messages are often cryptic and terribly verbose, it is still very helpful to post them in these cases.

Comment: Thanks for your posts, that was really quick! I edited the question to contain more detail.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is because Rcpp attributes, which compiles the C++ source files you make into `RcppExports.cpp`, does not copy over the `using namespace arma;` statements into there.

This is tricky, since different files might use different namespaces, so the attributes parser can't just copy all the `using namespace ...` statements into `RcppExports.cpp` -- it just defaults to using the `Rcpp` namespace. If we just copied all the `using namespace` statements willy nilly into `RcppExports.cpp` there could surely be conflicts.

Anyway, the fix is either to explicitly prefix `arma::` or you can modify the `RcppExports.cpp` file to have the `using namespace arma;` at the top (but you'd have to do this each time after calling `compileAttributes()`).

Comment: Oh, good hunch. That is plausible.  I, for one, use explicit `arma::` in my code.

Comment: Otherwise you can have `use namespace arma; ` in the `inst/include/test2.h` which `compileAttribute` will automatically `#include`.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, and for providing Rcpp and RcppArmadillo in the first place! They really boost the attractiveness of R for much of my current work (MCMC sampling for Bayesian time series models).